# DuckTyping and identifying between str and list types when passed as func parameters in Python

Tags: python

I understand ducktyping is one of the best practices within Python.

If I have a function `func` that expects a `list` as its parameter, how do I make sure that the user is not passing in a string that is getting converted to an individual `list` of chars while following the ducktyping principle?

```
def func(hosts): 
      # assume hosts is a list 
      for host in hosts: 
          dns_lookup(host)
```

Example:

1) Valid input `func(['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com']`: works

2) Invalid input `func('www.google.com')`: garbage input, fails later in the process

Answer (score 3):

- Let the user pass a string if they want:

  ```
  def func(hosts): 
      if isinstance(hosts, str):
          hosts = [hosts]
      for host in hosts: 
          dns_lookup(host)
  ```
- Raise an exception if `hosts` is *not* a list (or perhaps also a set/tuple, change as you wish):

  ```
  def func(hosts):
      expected_types = (list, set, tuple) 
      if not isinstance(hosts, expected_types ):
          raise TypeError('Expected one of {}, got {} instead'.format(expected_types , type(hosts)))
      for host in hosts: 
          dns_lookup(host)
  ```
- Not check at all, and rely on `dns_lookup` to raise an exception if it gets an invalid host (which will eventually happen if `hosts` is a string):

  ```
  def func(hosts):
      try:
          for host in hosts: 
              dns_lookup(host)
      # hopefully dns_lookup raises a TypeError if it gets an invalid host
      except TypeError:
          raise
  ```

You could also use type annotations but keep in mind that these are only advisory and do not affect runtime (unless you are using mypy)

Comment: is this really following the duck-typing paradigm though? I'm not saying it's incorrect, I'm legitimately curious

Comment: but isn't the whole idea of duck-typing is to avoid explicit type checks?

Comment: @wpercy well, the duck-typing "idiom" says that `func` should not care about the type of `hosts` whatsoever, but OP is asking how to make sure it will not break if `hosts` is a string. There is no other way to do that other than explicitly check the type of `hosts`.

Comment: @Neel You asked how to check if `hosts` is not a string. You can't do that without checking what is the type of `hosts`

Comment: @DeepSpace okay, that was my interpretation too (that there's no effective way to duck-type in this scenario)

Comment: @Neel @wpercy Well, I **assume** `dns_lookup` will break if it does not get a valid hostname which will be the case if `host` is a string. OP can try to rely on that. I added that as a option

Comment: By definition, duck-typing means doing nothing (no type checking at all).

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that your func expects an iterable of strings, each string being an hostname; but a single string is a valid iterable of single-letter strings. So passing a string does technically work but does not satisfy the functional logic. So you must "help" your func decide what to do.

You could do it in multiple ways, here are 2 acceptable practices:

1. Type checking:

Check if hosts is a `str` and convert it to a single-item list first:

```
def func(hosts): 
      if isinstance(hosts, str):
          hosts = [hosts]
      # assume hosts is a list 
      for host in hosts: 
          dns_lookup(host)
```

note: this is Python 3 code, if you want to support both 2 and 3 your should check types against `six.string_types` and not `str`.

2. Using argument packing:

Make your `func()` accept multiple hosts as arguments:

```
def func(*hosts): 
  # hosts is a list of all arguments passed to this function
  for host in hosts: 
      dns_lookup(host)
```

your `func()` must then be called like this:

```
func("host1", "host2", "hosts3")
```

If you already have a list of hosts, Python can unpack it to pass it as multiple arguments:

```
hosts = ["host1", "host2", "hosts3"]
func(*hosts)
```